# how to set camera for each players in photon with playmaker?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon, playmaker

I work on my online project which is online and used playmaker to make that, now I wanna set the camera for each player, for example we have 2 players in the room, blue player and red player, how I can set the camera for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, My Camera has some logic to target a specific gameobject, each players check if "is mine" is true, and in that case will broadcast an event like "I AM THE LOCAL PLAYER" and your camera fsm will catch that, store the sender of that event and becomes now the camera target.